# Кавычки, запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, кавычки

***— На следующем ходу конь может прыгнуть на форпост.***

***— Серьëзно? То есть на форпост, а не заберëт ферзя, стоящего под его боем?***

***— Имеется в виду(,) («)на отход ферзя(»).***

Что думаете?

Answer (score 1):

Всё будет по-кошачьи, т. е. по-правильному, если вы так, сэр-пэр, напишете.

`— На следующем ходу конь может прыгнуть на форпост.`

`— Серьëзно? То есть на форпост, а не заберëт ферзя, стоящего под его боем?`

`— Имеется в виду «на отход ферзя».`

Ещё пример:

`— Мой кот родил восемьдесят сегодня котят.`

`— Чё?!`

`— Ой! Я имел в виду «моя кошка».`

Answer (score 1):

А мне кажется, что **с запятой** лучше:

— Имеется в виду, ***на отход ферзя***.

Возможно, это БСП, то есть во второй части **неполное** предложение.

Но это мое **предположение** (надо разбираться в шахматной терминологии).

Вместо кавычек используем **курсив.**

Comment: А вот я шахматную терминологию знаю хорошо))

Comment: То есть и запятая, и курсив?)

Comment: Да, именно так. У них разные функции. Но курсив не обязателен. Можно убрать. Шахматисты и так понимают, о чем речь.

Comment: Хорошо, подумаю и над вашим и над предложением Леопольда.

Comment: Да, следующий ход ваш)